# Using Selenium functions inside Tkinter buttons for a Python program

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, tkinter

Can we use selenium functions inside a Tkinter Button? so that when i Click the button it performs the Selenium function. similarly create few more buttons for other steps performed in selenium.

Comment: you can add. Can you elaborate your question, which selenium method you want to use?

Comment: i am using selenium to open a website then login and filling up different cells there from my excel sheet. then repeat this process from excel to this website. after each operation ask for permission to do the next step in the loop

Comment: in selenium i can run the program but unable to do that in tkinter for button click

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can something do like following-

```
def myTask():
    #Your selenium code Here
    #You can use loop and pandas to iterate over Excel



b = Button(root,textvariable=button_text, text="Click me", font="lucida 8 bold", padx=8, pady=8,width="20", command=myTask)
button_text.set("Selenium Method")
b.place(relx=.46, rely=.7, anchor=CENTER)
```

Comment: NameError: name 'button_text' is not defined it gives this error now

Comment: @DipankarGogoi firstly declare it as button_text = StringVar() and import libraries. Hope it will hep u

Comment: it did. thank you Vishav. i had not defined it so it was not working

Comment: one more question for you @vishav when i try to use selenium driver for calling the active window in another button click  it does not work. it says driver is not defined. is there any solution to this problem. so that i can use the window opened by the driver from the previous button click to perform other functions

Comment: @DipankarGogoi are you talking about window handle value?

Comment: its done now. i hadn't defined the variable as global so it was not working